# How to import Django conventional structure into a new project

Tags: python, django, windows, pycharm

I am new to Django. How can I create a standard structure of Django in PyCharm? There is no any file like `apps.py` or `models.py` when creating a new Django project in Python. How can I import all those standard files into my project?

Answer (score 1):

run this command in terminal.

```
django-admin startapp myapp
```

i suggest you to follow django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/